# "QTableWidget::selectedItems" returns an empty list

Tags: qt, qtablewidget

I have a QTableWidget with one column with a widget, and others with data. The column with the widget is shown, and all other columns are hidden.

```
foreach (BillHeader *billHeader, billHeaderList)
{
    m_pBillTable->insertRow(i);

    itemWidget = new LookupItem;
    itemWidget->setImage(1);
    ...
    m_pBillTable->setCellWidget(i, 0, itemWidget);

    tableItem = new QTableWidgetItem(billHeader->billNumber);
    tableItem->setTextAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
    m_pBillTable->setItem(i, 1, tableItem);
    ...

    m_pBillTable->hideColumn(1);
    ...
```

I have a signal slot connected as below:

```
connect(m_pOkButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(handleOkClick()));
```

When the <kbd>Ok</kbd> button is clicked, I try to get the selected item and get data from the widget set to it:

```
void OrderLookup::handleOkClick()
{
qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<"Invoked";

QList<QTableWidgetItem*> itemList = m_pBillTable->selectedItems();
qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<itemList.count();
if (!itemList.isEmpty())
{
    int row = itemList.at(0)->row();
    qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<row;
    LookupItem *item = (LookupItem*)m_pBillTable->cellWidget(row, 0);

    if (NULL != item)
    {
        QString billNumber = item->getBillNumber();
        emit orderLookupComplete(billNumber);
        accept();
    }
}

qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<"Exits";
}
```

But I am getting the list count as zero.

The row is getting selected and gets highlighted.

I’ve set some properties to the table widget as below:

```
    m_pBillTable->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectRows);
    m_pBillTable->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    m_pBillTable->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus);
```

Why is the list count empty?

Answer (score 2):

```
QItemSelectionModel *itemModel = m_pBillTable->selectionModel();
QModelIndexList indexList = itemModel->selectedRows();
qDebug()<<Q_FUNC_INFO<<"IndexList Count"<<indexList.count();

if (!indexList.isEmpty())
{
    int row = indexList.at(0).row();
```